# Removing repeated elements from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to Haskell. I just wonder how to implement a function to remove the repeat element from an array. for example, [1,1,1,3,4,2,2,3], the result should be [1,3,4,2]. I don't want to use some exist functions like element and implement this by using recursion. My idea is to compare x:xs, if x is a repeat element then do the recursion, else rerun the function. Is that correct and how to implement this by code?

Comment: Nitpicking: `[1,1,1,3,4,2,2,3]` is not an array, it's a linked list.  The performance characteristics are very different.

Comment: actually, this is a part of work, I can't figure it out. other part I already finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cannot assume any ordering between the elements (i.e. you don't know if it's an instance of `Ord`), then you must use `nub` like one poster has already mentioned. Unfortunately this is O(n^2).

If your elements implement `Ord`, then you can sort the list in O(nlog(n)) and then remove adjacent elements recursively (which adds just O(n) to the overall runtime). Something like this:

```
remove_dups :: (Ord a, Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
remove_dups xs = remove $ sort xs
  where
    remove []  = []
    remove [x] = [x]
    remove (x1:x2:xs)
      | x1 == x2  = remove (x1:xs)
      | otherwise = x1 : remove (x2:xs)
```

Pretty interesting problem. We often need to do this sort of thing. =)

**Edit**

I didn't notice the result you gave is not in non-decreasing order. The above code will produce `[1,2,3,4]` instead, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Well, is7s, the poster doesn't say it's for his/her homework. I answered believing that it was not.

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at the `nub` function provided by Haskell.

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/list.html

Which is this code:

```
nub                     :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub                      = nubBy (==)

nubBy                   :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
nubBy eq []              = []
nubBy eq (x:xs)          = x : nubBy eq (filter (y -> not (eq x y)) xs)
```

actually, I found a webpage which shows you a more efficient implementation than the one provided by Haskell:
http://buffered.io/posts/a-better-nub/

Comment: @augustss I answered before it was tagged homework. **edited** I found the part on homework policy (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) although it is not official, I will keep it in mind. On the other hand, mind you that this is the result of a single google search, and that it is merely the implementation provided with the haskell library. In other words, I haven't shown him anything he couldn't EASILY find himself.

Comment: If performance is important then consider [`nubOrd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/attachment/ticket/2717/nub.patch) too.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track: you're considering the head of a list (`x` in your example) and the tail (`xs`). As you suggest, you need to do two things:

1. Write a function that removes any duplicates of `x` in `xs`.
2. Treat the rest of the list... now that any duplicates of `x` in `xs` are gone, how do you procede? Try it out manually on paper and observe what your brain does.

Try to solve the first task first, and make sure that the function you wrote works on some testcases (try it out in GHCi or something until you're satisfied that it works).

For the second task it again helps immensely to try and observe how your brain procedes when you solve this problem manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem, the desired one probably depends upon what your course has covered this far.

I'll observe that 'exists' functions often have logarithmic running time, depending upon the data structure used, and building the nicest data structures requires at worst 'n log n' time.

Don't worry if this sounds like gibberish.  You'll learn about running time in an algorithms or complexity theory course.  I'm only saying that a well designed exists functions works much faster than you realize.

As an aside, there is something called a hash function that lets you make more fine grained time-space trade offs for larger arrays, but that's beyond the scope of your current course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning Haskell and I wrote this Code.I think it solves your problem. I did it the simplest way I could think of.

```
takeRep :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]  
takeRep [] = []
takeRep (x:xs)
    | checkIt x xs = takeRep xs
    | otherwise = x:takeRep xs

checkIt :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
checkit _ [] = False
checkIt n (x:xs)
    | n == x = True
    | otherwise = checkIt n xs
```