# Haskell - removing repeated elements from an ADT list in an ADT

Tags: haskell

Hello Stackoverflow community, another fairly elementary question on my behalf:

There was a question asked some five years back which asked "removing repeated elements from a list in Haskell." I have something similar to ask, albiet with a certain degree of complication.

Say that I have these data types:

```
data Library = Library {borrower :: String, book :: [Book]}
data Book = Book {title :: String, barcode :: Integer}
```

Then say I have the function:

```
addBook :: Book -> Library -> Library
addBook book library = library {book = book : getBooks library}
```

where getBooks is simply a function that extracts [Book] from Library.

Obviously, this function is fine as long as Ralph doesn't borrow duplicates of books. Nevertheless, if he does, then there will be a duplicate in the list of Books, which is not desirable.

How would I go about writing a function which returns the current [Book], however also removes any duplicates? I tried the method in the question aforementioned at the beginning of the post, however the compiler complains it specifically wants [Book] not [a].

Link to the previous question: 
[Removing repeated elements from a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227218/removing-repeated-elements-from-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: How about using `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`? Note that you need to provide (or derive) an `Eq` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

First make `Book` an instance of `Eq`:

```
data Book = Book {title :: String, barcode :: Integer} deriving Eq
```

Then fix the function `addBook` to filter books that are already in the library (by using the `elem` function):

```
addBook :: Book -> Library -> Library
addBook book library = if elem book (getBooks library)
  then library -- The library already contains this book
  else library {book = book : getBooks library}
```

The `elem` function has the following signature:

```
elem :: a -> [a] -> Bool
```